# How to protect Mars/Moon mission crews against meteors?

Tags: mars, the-moon, mission-design, future-missions, meteors

Humans are expected to return to the Moon (see [Artemis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artemis_program)) and maybe go to Mars (see [this](https://www.space.com/nasa-plans-astronauts-mars-mission-30-days#:%7E:text=NASA%20aims%20to%20launch%20astronauts,distance%20between%20Earth%20and%20Mars.) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Mars_program)) within a decade or two.

Meteors frequently strike the surface of both the Moon and Mars (one can't really count on a thick atmosphere to burn them up). How much of a danger would this be for the mission's crew and how are Nasa/SpaceX/etc. mitigating the risks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The technologies are probably not going to be much different from the ones existing right now. The ISS doesn't really benefit that much from atmospheric shielding in its current orbit, so they have to manage collisions the same way any other crewed mission will.

The main difference is that for the ISS, the first line of defense against collisions is detection and avoidance, which will be less efficient for a deep space
mission, but not impossible. With the right onboard equipment and even Earth-based detection infrastructure is possible to detect the biggest incoming chunks of rocks or space debris and maneuver away from them.

For anything that is not detectable, the next option is shielding and there are different ways to implement it ([ESA Hypervelocity impacts and shielding](https://www.esa.int/Space_Safety/Space_Debris/Hypervelocity_impacts_and_protecting_spacecraft)). One way is to use a very thick plank of high-density material, however, that will increase the weight of the vehicle, fuel consumption, and cost, and you will always have an upper limit to what you can deflect in terms of size and velocity.

The second option is to use something called a Whipple shield, which is also currently used in several different combinations in ISS. In this case, you use several thin layers of carefully selected materials, where the first layer is designed to break up the incoming piece of debris or micrometeoroid into a cloud of material that is then way more manageable for the following layers to stop. The advantage of this is that you can boost your shielding capabilities with a lower weight penalty by properly selecting the materials. For this, you can use materials like Kevlar, Nomex, and aluminium.

I've also seen some crazy proposals (although I wasn't able to find them), like deploying a sail-like Wipple shield in front of the vehicle which could improve weight and provide a big shielding cone area for the whole vehicle.

Edit:

To address the original question.
Technology alternatives for the Moon and Mars are tricky because there is no design ready for manufacturing, only concepts, and early proposals, so it is necessary to lean heavily into speculation space, so please keep that in mind even though I'll try to keep it as grounded as possible.

Either on the Moon or Mars, detection will also need to be the first line of defense. In the Moon case, the risks are similar to the transit case because there is no atmosphere, but it has a distinct difference that the base can't be moved.

If something is coming too close to the base and is too big for comfort, the logical step is evacuation, at least at the beginning. It can be expected that as the Moon infrastructure and permanent settlements are developed, potential defense systems could be put in place, like kinetic interceptors for the bigger rocks (DART style), but that falls completely into the long-term development field.

For smaller meteoroids, the main options are still things like Whipple shields, using the regolith to build a shell around the habitat as a radiation/small impact shield ([Regolith shielding](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0094576508003858?casa_token=x3hF7v3VscsAAAAA:LYaotbtapLkleJPr-Zb9OWrsifKL0_PX7XtgCbCD65cuF59TJxd9GBe1Q9CXNWP6TfBApLKzz7c)), or even building the habitats inside lava tubes ([Lava Tubes](https://www.space.com/moon-colonists-lunar-lava-tubes.html)). Keep in mind that the regolith and lava tubes options are being considered primarily for radiation shielding right now since it is considered a higher priority threat, and there aren't really any mature designs available.

The exact same alternatives are available on Mars: Detection, evacuation, some type of shielding, kinetic impactors... but the difference is that Mars does have an atmosphere and it will burn the smaller rocks, metoroids, and debris.

For either the Moon or Mars, the infrastructure for any of the protective measures will need to be installed first. Monitoring the space around the Moon can be done to some degree with the hardware available right now, but for Mars, some early warning system will have to be put in place.

Now, the fact that those technologies could be used, does not mean that they will. Protecting against impacts is, like everything in space, a trade-off, and this is done as part of the mission/system design process where an acceptable risk level is defined, the real risk estimated, and if it is unacceptable, it is mitigated somehow (for example improving detection or shielding) until that risk falls under the acceptable limit.

In the case of the Moon, there have been impact surveys that can allow us to assess the rate of impacts and understand the risk ([Lunar Impact Monitoring](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/marshall/news/lunar/overview.html)). I'm assuming that the more likely outcome is that, for at least the initial missions, the risk will be acceptable using shielding technologies like the ones used right now in the ISS.

In the Mars case, it is necessary to first understand how much risk of a considerable impact there is and what mitigation measures need to be taken. And is also perfectly possible that the technologies we have right now could be considered good enough for the initial mission.

Comment: my read of OP's question is that this concerns protection on the surface of the Moon and Mars--not micrometeroid impacts, but meteors of a size that they could impact the Martian surface.

Comment: +1  Incidentally, the Giotto spacecraft used a Whipple shield to protect it on its approach to Halley's comet https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giotto_(spacecraft)#Design

Comment: OP here, @ErinAnne is right. That's exactly what I meant. In its current form, this response is not exactly addressing my question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!